# Infinitesimal generator of a semigroup with parameter

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, hyperbolic-pde, cauchy-problem

When we talk about evolution equation the first idea that comes to the mind is the semigroups theory. This theory deals with Cauchy problems of the form $$\frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial t}} = Au,$$
where $A$ is an operator on Banach spaces.
My question is: is there any theory which deals with evolution problems of the form $$\frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial t}} = A(t)u,$$
where now $A$ may depend on $t$?

Comment: You could fill libraries with that, for example start here: https://books.google.com/books/about/Equations_of_evolution.html?id=Dn6zAAAAIAAJ

Comment: Multiplicative ergodic theory is highly relevant, providing the time dependence of $A(t)$ is stationary.

Answer (score 1):

You can see these two books:

1) Daniel Daners and Pablo Koch Medina: Abstract evolution equations, periodic problems and applications

2) Peter Hess: Periodic-Parabolic Boundary Value Problems and Positivity